# Copy cert from LocalComputer to CurrentUser with C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, x509certificate

As the title says, I need to programmatically copy a cert (given the thumbprint) from the LocalComputer store to the CurrentUser store. I've been digging around in the X509Certificate2 definitions and trying stuff, but nothing seems to be working. Here is what I have so far

```
certPath = "@"C:\%temp%\Cert.pfx";
certPass = "CertPassHere";    

X509Store localMachineStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
localMachineStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection certificate = localMachineStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "certThumbprint", true);
byte[] rawCertData = certificate[0].Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, certPass);
File.WriteAllBytes(certPath, rawCertData);
localMachineStore.Close();

X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Import(certPath, certPass, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
X509Store currentUserStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Subject is: '{0}'", cert.Subject);
    Console.WriteLine("Issuer is:  '{0}'", cert.Issuer);
    currentUserStore.Add(cert);
}

currentUserStore.Close();
File.Delete(certPath);
```

I feel like I'm somewhat on the right track here, but any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: "nothing seems to be working"... What is happening?

Comment: I'm not seeing the cert pop up in the CurrentUser store, and it is marked as exportable in the LocalComputer store

Comment: Also not totally sure if copying to a file and importing from there is the preferred approach?

Answer (score 2):

- Saving it to a file is unnecessary, since you can load the PFX from the `byte[]` directly.
- You don't seem to have a call to `currentUserStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite)`, is the code finishing, or throwing a CryptographicException?
- You need to import the PFX with `X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet` because the private key will "remember" that it was exported from the machine keystore, and it wants to go back there.
- Passing `true` as the third argument to `X509Certificate2Collection.Find` is usually not what you want, it's mostly only handy when searching by subject, to ignore expired things.

.

```
string thumbprint = IAssumeYouHaveThisForReal();

X509Certificate2Collection certificates = localMachineStore.Certificates.Find(
    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
    thumbprint,
    false);

byte[] tempPfx = certificates[0].Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "hi");

X509Certificate2 copyWithUserKey = new X509Certificate2(
    tempPfx,
    "hi",
    X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet /*| X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable if you like */);

X509Store currentUserMy = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
currentUserMy.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
currentUserStore.Add(copyWithUserKey);

certificates = currentUserStore.Certificates.Find(
    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
    thumbprint,
    false);

if (certificates.Count != 1)
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
```